# (X)Ubuntu boot hangs after power off

Tags: xubuntu, 17.04

My Xubuntu 17.04 hangs on boot. My pc was shutted down when the electricity was cut off. And when I turn it on, it's trying to fix some "orphaned node". After this it show me this message no matter how long. Here shot of my screen.

[image: shot of screen]

But I can reboot PC by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
. It shows Xubuntu reboot splash screen.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: There is no such thing as "boot after power off", because the system is supposed to shut down and halt in this case, not to (re)boot. Please rephrase your question to explain clearly what you do, what you expect, and what is going wrong (and when).

Comment: sorry for my bad english. My pc was shutted down when the electricity was cut off. And when I turn it on, it's trying to fix some "orphaned node". After this it show me this message no matter how long.

Comment: The problem is not bad English, but an incomplete and misleading description of the problem. Your comment tells a completely different story than what I would've concluded from your initial question. Now if you take the time and update the text of your question in appropriate detail it will surely increase your chances of getting helpful answers.